# iphone how to customize UITableViewCell cell.textlabel and cell.detailtextlabel programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitableview

In my iPhone App In table view cell I want to dispaly one  main title and 5 subtitlessubtitles 
suppose item1 as main title and item2 , item3 , item4 , item5 and item6 as subtitles,

for that i have saperate two arrays for passing the values in table view cell 
one for cell.textLabel.text=
second for cell.detailTextLabel.text

[image]

now I want the flexibility to make item2 as maintitle and want to add item1 to subtitle

[image]

How can I set title and subtitle programmatically from single array? and any of them as

Please Help and Suggest,

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass the UITableViewCell and add as many labels you want. Take a look to Apple CustomTableViewCell sample code. You can get it from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318).

Answer (score 1):

Create a .xib with whatever format you'd like and load it as the nib for your cells. You can then tag each UILabel and refer to them by tag:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"youCustomCellNibName" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = yourCell; // UITableViewCell property defined in your interface
        self.yourCell = nil;
    }

    // Grab the cell data
    NSArray *cellArray = [yourArrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell

    // Main Title
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];

    // A subtitle
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [cellArray objectAtIndex:1];

    //... etc., setting all of your labels to the appropriate array item
    return cell;
}
```

Gives you lots of flexibility to create the exact cell you want and to easily modify it. No need to subclass and do it all in code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check this out: [Custom UITableViewCell done programatically](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/)